# Grand (as in parents) -- singular or plural?

Tags: meaning, grammatical-number

In his song ["White Wine in the Sun"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fCNvZqpa-7Q), Tim Minchin sings

> I'll be seeing ... my grand and my Mum.

This apparently stands for grandparents, but what is the 'default' visualization of that word by native speakers? Do you see multiple grandparents or, for instance, one grandmother?

For me as a non-native English speaker, the latter seems more natural, since, along the musical motion and harmony change, the scene's attention is somewhat focusing gradually on the Mum character, going from plural of *sisters* to singular of *Mum*, dragging the intermediate point to singular.

It could also be undefined, so that you'd only sense just a vague odor of grandparenting. Is this the case?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you look at [the lyrics to “White Wine in the Sun”](http://www.lyricsmode.com/lyrics/t/tim_minchin/white_wine_in_the_sun.html), you’ll see that he actually sings,

> I’ll be seeing my dad,
>   My brother and sisters, my gran and my mum.

In Britain, *[gran](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/gran)* is a name for a grandmother (probably short for *granny*, which is short for *grandma*, which is short for *grandmother*). The plural, then, would be *grans*, but I don’t think you’d hear it often. More likely, British folk would use a different word like *grannies* or *grandmothers* to talk about more than one gran.

Comment: Should also have provided all the same details for *grandfather* and *grandparents* as well, to clarify why the reference could *not* have been to *grandparents*. OP thought it "apparently stands for *grandparents*."